# Can't read same InputStream twice

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a an InputStream as a parameter, which works just fine when I read it for the first time, however, reading the same InputStream doesn't work. I just can't get `mark()` and `reset()`to work. Anyone know how to reset this? I'm reading a .txt file. The file contains spawn values for enemy objects that don't reappear, since the inputstream mark(?) is at the end, I guess?

```
readTxt(InputStream resource){
//resource is a .txt as ResourceStream
arrayList = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why don't you store values at first read ? explain more, store nameFile and stream twice not possible ?

Answer (score 5):

`mark()` only work if the input stream supported it (you can check by `markSupported()`.

It does not work for every stream.

One way to read the input stream is to copy content of input stream to an array and re-read the array:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int byteCount;
while ((byteCount = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
}
byte[] source = output.toByteArray();

// Now you have ability to reread the "secondary" input stream:
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(source);
```

Comment: Tested if it supports, it does. Will try to re-read with copying to array.

Comment: If your input stream support it, you should call `mark(int byteCountAbleToReset)`. And later call `reset()` to go back `byteCountAbleToReset` bytes in stream.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `fileStream.mark(arrayList.size());`and then 
`fileStream.reset();` but it didn't work

Comment: You must call `mark()` before read from input stream. And the number be passed is the number of bytes you want to go back, it's definitely greater than `list.size()`

Comment: Yeah, calling mark() before worked, I had it after the reading part

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Since the InputStream was `markSupported()`, I could use the `mark()`and `reset()`.

```
//mark 0, before you start reading your file
inputStream.mark(0);


//read your InputStream here
read(inputStream)...

//reset the stream, so it's ready to be read from the start again. 
inputStream.reset();
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to read the stream if it's been read internally. I don't receive it in my code until after Spring already called read function. Is it possible?